# Is it possible to create a derived component that renders the base component inside of another Razor component?

Tags: c#, blazor

I would like to create a derived component where the base component renders inside of another Razor component.  Something like this

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<AdditionalComponent>
    @{
        base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
    }
</AdditionalComponent>
```

However, the derived component never renders its `BaseComponent`.  It only displays the `AdditionalComponent`

Here's an example showing the issue.

**BaseComponent.razor**

```
<h3>BaseComponent</h3>
```

**AdornmentComponent.razor**

```
<div>
    <h3>Top of Adornment</h3>
    @ChildContent
    <h3>Bottom of Adornment</h3>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

**DerivedComponent.razor**

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<AdornmentComponent>
    @{
        base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
    }
</AdornmentComponent>
```

**Test.razor**

```
@page "/Test"

<DerivedComponent />
```

I want it to render like

```
<h3>Top of Adornment</h3>
<h3>BaseComponent</h3>
<h3>Bottom of Adornment</h3>
```

But instead it renders like

```
<h3>Top of Adornment</h3>
<h3>Bottom of Adornment</h3>
```

Comment: Sound hacky, but I tested and it's work. Can you show a minimal reproductive code?

Comment: I added an example.  I must have been doing something which was causing the exceptions (I was using the MudBlazor library and inheriting from one of its controls).  But when I try it with my own components, the control doesn't fully render like I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler transform the razor code to csharp code, before to compile to msil. You can see this intermediate compilation result by adding in csproj :

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
  <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>.</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Remove="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If you want display this files by the solution explorer, click on "Show all files".

---

The generated csharp from **DerivedComponent.razor** is :

```cs
protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
{
    __builder.OpenComponent<AdornmentComponent>(0);
    __builder.AddAttribute(1, "ChildContent", __builder2 => {
        base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
    });
    __builder.CloseComponent();
}
```

We can see that the wrong `RenderTreeBuilder` was passed to `AdornmentComponent`.

**DerivedComponent.razor** need to be fix to use `__builder2` to render `AdornmentComponent`'s child content :

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<AdornmentComponent>
@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder2);
}
</AdornmentComponent>
```

---

It's seem to work, but it's also seem hacky... I would rather recommend to  use the solution suggested by @RBee.

Or my favorite, a composition like :

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<AdornmentComponent>
    <BaseComponent />
</AdornmentComponent>
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation.  I didn't understand where `__builder` was coming from, but you answered that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the base components `BuildRenderTree` to generate a `RenderFragment` field then display that.

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<AdornmentComponent>
    @BaseContent
</AdornmentComponent>

@code {
    public RenderFragment BaseContent => base.BuildRenderTree;
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOmxuCQOekQfueqx)

Or, as @vernou mentioned in the comments. You can directly generate the `RenderFragment` in the markup by prefixing it with a '@', **without** the curly braces.

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<AdornmentComponent>
    @base.BuildRenderTree
</AdornmentComponent>
```

Comment: Nice. Put `@base.BuildRenderTree` directly in the razor template seems to work also.

Comment: @vernou you're right. That works as well.

Comment: But with the property, this sound more clean... And a derived class from `DerivedComponent` can use the `BaseComponent.BuildRenderTree`.